# How can I prevent the browser's default history back action for the backspace button with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, events

Is there a way to prevent the default action from occurring when the user presses backspace in a browser?

I don't need to prevent the user from leaving, just from having the default backspace action. I need the backspace to do something different (it's a game).

I tried without success:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === Game.Key.BACK_SPACE)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
}, false);
```

If I put an alert inside the if, the alert will be shown for backspace key press. So, the keyCode is correct.

This has to work in Opera 10.6, Firefox 4, Chrome 6, Internet Explorer 9 and Safari 5.

Comment: Have you tried trapping `keypress` and/or `keyup` instead?

Comment: Which browser does this fail in?

Comment: Related Question: [SO: How can I prevent the backspace key from navigating back?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495219/how-can-i-prevent-the-backspace-key-from-navigating-back)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need `return false` or `e.stopPropagation()`; neither will make any difference in a listener attached with `addEventListener`. Your code won't work in Opera, which only allows you to suppress the default browser behaviour in the `keypress` event, or IE <= 8, which doesn't support `addEventListener`. The following should work in all browsers, so long as you don't already have `keydown` and `keypress` event handlers on the `document`.

**EDIT**: It also now filters out events that originated from an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element:

```
function suppressBackspace(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;

    if (evt.keyCode == 8 && !/input|textarea/i.test(target.nodeName)) {
        return false;
    }
}

document.onkeydown = suppressBackspace;
document.onkeypress = suppressBackspace;
```

Comment: While this works, it prevents inputs from working. It shouldn't prevent backspace on input elements.

Comment: That would be true of your solution too if it worked. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to do it the other way -- prevent the user from leaving the page rather than trying to stop all backspace actions?

Comment: No, you can't stop the user from leaving the page. The browser prevents this, and rightly: it's up to the user if they want to leave the page. There is an `unload` event (and `beforeunload` in many browsers) that fires as the page is about to close or go somewhere else, but you can't suppress that event.

Comment: unless of course its an application and the user could inadvertently lose there work... browsers now for more than classic websites.

Comment: @nodrog: That's what the `beforeunload` event is for: it allows the page to at least display a warning and ask the user if they really want to leave the page.

Comment: Thanks Tim, you are right. And I have learned something new... tx

Comment: I don't understand.  You say "You don't need `return false`" but that appears to be the method you are using.  Also, this method does not seem to work (in Firefox anyway).

Comment: Ok, I figured out why.  If you are debugging using Firebug and have a breakpoint in your code before the `return false`, Firefox will STILL murder your page and go "back" the instant you hit your breakpoint!

Comment: @Michael: `return false` works in my solution because I'm using DOM0 event handler methods (`onkeydown`, `onkeypress`) rather than `addEventListener()`, which is what the OP is using.

Comment: @MarekBar Example page?

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to simply have the fix for yourself, without affecting other users when scripting into the web page, read below.

Here's some solutions that only change the browser you are using:
- Firefox on Linux "unmapped" the backspace behavior since 2006 so it's not affected; (at any rate, it was simply set to scroll up before then)
- Chrome has just announced that it will do the same from now on; (http://forums.theregister.co.uk/forum/1/2016/05/20/chrome_deletes_backspace/)
- Firefox on Windows can be set to ignore backspace by going into about:config and changing the backspace_action setting to 2; (http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.backspace_action)
- Safari ?!

Comment: as an enduser using Jupyter notebooks, this answer is a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

I found at Telerik's page script ready to use. Script blocks back button action: by clicking  in browser back button and backspace on page. This script works. I'm using it in my project.
http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/general/disable-backspace-from-master-page.aspx