# How is Facebook handling their onbeforeunload confirmation dialog?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, onbeforeunload

When browsing Facebook in the latest Chrome on OSX, I noticed that beginning to type in a comment box and clicking another link or pressing the back button triggers a confirmation window asking if I'd like to leave:

[image: Facebook Confirmation Dialog]

Being an old school developer, I had believed that the only possibility was to attach an `onbeforeunload` event to the page to handle the back button click. I know you can do a global binding on the anchors to simulate `onbeforeunload`, but I was surprised they managed to have a custom styled confirmation and not the stock, ugly looking confirmation dialog.

**How did they do it? Is this some kind of HTML5 window history or pushState event trigger?**

Comment: They're probably handling link clicks and `popstate` themselves and always suppressing the default action.

Comment: As you can see here http://www.businessinsider.com/facebook-saves-stuff-you-start-typing-and-the-delete-2013-12 they have a much more higher logic and implement stuff like that question in their sleeps. ;)

Comment: @SLaks it appears as though `popstate` is the likely culprit as you indicated. Hopefully someone posts up a proof of concept combining the two (link binding and popstate). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onpopstate

Comment: Ok, last thing. `popstate` does only work [on same document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onpopstate), means you not only have to use `AJAX`, also an `.htacess` routing to for example all "documents" to `index.php`. Then you can prevent the event on your same page!

Comment: Now Facebook used native dialog at least tested with Chrome Version 49.0.2623.110 m

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found this [answer](http://www.irt.org/script/311.htm) on Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript).

This handles the `onbeforeunload`.
To test this in your browser simply put

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "Your work will be lost."; };
```

into your console, press enter and try the back button.

## Now for your real answer:

Facebook handles the pressing of the back button in the above described way (as I tested out) and the `cancel(l)ing` of a comment by clicking on another link on the page with the `div` that pops up in your question.

## Edit

If it would be possible to prevent the browser from leaving the `AJAX` context, this would work (add it in the console):

```
window.onpopstate = function (event) {
 alert("location: " + document.location);
 event.preventDefault();
 return false;
}
```

I answered here since facebook does not do it, which was your initial question. But I sincerely hope someone proves it wrong!

Comment: `onbeforeunload` is not what I'm looking for. Thanks though.

Comment: I know, but when I click on the back button on facebook, when typing a comment, there only pops the ugly dialogue up!?!

Comment: Similarly this concept with `popstate` does not work when leaving the page, only save in an `AJAX` environment, as my first link describes. First you would have to be able to disable the back button at all, to catch the event. But when you are leaving the `ajaxified` environment, your script gets lost with the click on the back button!?!