# firefox browser back button doesn't refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My app is running fine on chrome but in Firefox (v 32.0) , it's creating one problem.

As after log out, if go back by clicking the browser's back button. It should not allow to go back and load the previously visited page.

I have coded well to achieve this and works fine everywhere. It works fine in chrome also. But in case of firefox browser's back button, it's not refreshing/reloading the page and simply shows the previously visited page.

I think If I make it reload the page on back button clicking then it'll be solved.

For this, I tried by the following code on that page:

```
<input type="hidden" id="refreshed" value="no">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    onload=function(){
      console.log("method called.......");
    var e=document.getElementById("refreshed");
    if(e.value=="no")
     {
       e.value="yes";
      }
    else
      {
       e.value="no";
       location.reload();
      }
    }
    </script>
```

But it didn't work.

Any suggestion please ?

Comment: Did you try edit meta tags to no-cache/expires -1?

Comment: Consider using the HTML5 History API instead of relying on stateless behaviours.

Comment: yeah I tried it but it's not working.

Comment: @ Niels Keurentjes... Any example/link please.

Comment: try adding `Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store` header to the page in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that your code works, I cannot see how it will ever reach the `else` because `onload` happens only once at page load, and `reload` will call it again on the next page load. To prevent the back button, you can use `window.onbeforeunload`.

More details here : [how to stop browser back button using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript)