# Use the back button of the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two html pages: mainpage.html and secondPage.html
The first page works like the layout:

```
 <div id="header"></div>
 <div id="home"></div>
 <div id="footer"></div>
```

the second:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

So when i click on a button in the home div i have a function that charge the #content inside the #home, until here everything works good. In few words i refresh only #home.
Now I want that when I click the back button of the browser I come back to the old home because now if i do this it goes to the previous page.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at this answer, maybe it help you...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript

Comment: Use history.pushState function, it works perfect in modern browsers.