# Prevent browser back button to not go to previous page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to prevent browser back button to not go to previous page.
For this I tried below code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
        function preventBack() { window.history.forward(); }
        setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
        window.onunload = function () { null };
    </script>
```

but when I click on browser back button continuously 2-3 times at one go, it again redirects to previous page. So my above code fails. 
I don't want user to go to previous page.

I tried this code as well:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        function disableBack() { window.history.forward() }

        window.onload = disableBack();
        window.onpageshow = function (evt) { if (evt.persisted) disableBack() }
    });

</script>
```

but this code is removing the scroller from browser and I am unable to scroll the page.

Please reply some solution. I tried searching many articles but could not find any solution.

Comment: I highly recommend considering some other options. In most cases, hijacking the back button like this is bad UX, which is probably why you're getting downvoted. Users shouldn't feel like a website is working against them, or "breaking" their browser.
For example. if going back puts your app in a bad state, have the previous page render a message explaining why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.history.forward(1);
 </script>
```

Or you may read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript)

Comment: For all solutions I am facing the issue that when I click on browser back button continuously 2-3 times at one go, it again redirects to previous page. So my above code fails. Please reply some other solution which work without this issue?

Comment: I set that in header of my pages and nothing wrong until now. Maybe you can leave your so called attribute(`windows.unload`,`$(document)`, etc) and set it in header without those attributes. Sometimes simple thing is the answer.