# how to disable the back button in my browser?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to disable back button in my webpage..list me the methods that i can do this...
`

```
   if($data->num_rows > 0){
       while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()){

         header('Location:../cashier.php');
       }
   }else{
       echo "Username and  Password is Incorrect...Try  Again";
   }
```

}
  ?>`

Comment: The code you have posted has got nothing to do with back button and browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to stop browser back button using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript)

Comment: I would say that is bad practice to alter the expected behaviour of the browser.  You'd be better served with an exit popup.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit of code that has worked wonderfully for me on all browsers except IE9 and below.
(Doing the pushState twice each time is overkill, but I like it anyway.)
You just need to modify the code that says "myCritera, myStuff" and the like.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (myCriteria == 'yes') {
        window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
            if (event.state) {
                if (window.history.state == null){
                    return;
                }
                $('#myStuff').hide();
                $('#myStuff2').hide();
                $('#otherStuff').show();
                window.history.pushState({},'', '');
                window.history.pushState({},'', '');
            }
        }, false);

        window.history.pushState({},'', '');
        window.history.pushState({},'', '');
    }
});
```

Comment: IE 11 has some weird quirks.  Recently had to revise code to use: window.history.pushState({},'', window.location.href);

Answer (score -1):

Here's my code which works good:

```
 var url = window.history.forward();
 window.history.go(-window.history.length);
```