# How to prevent back button after LOGIN in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have 2 pages `home.aspx` and `admin.aspx`

After successfully logging into `admin.aspx` when i click back button of browser, it does redirect to `home.aspx` but that i don't want.

I am checking session variable persistence on `home.aspx` but for some reason its not working!!

Here's the code

home.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["aname"] != null)//should work as session will not be null!
    {
        Response.Redirect("admin.aspx");
    }
    } //.....some code..after this 


        if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
        {

            Session["aname"] = TextBox11.Text;
            Response.Redirect("admin.aspx");
        }
```

`admin.aspx.cs` code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["aname"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("home.aspx"); 
    }

} //some code after this..

protected void logoutbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["aname"] = null;
    Session.Abandon();
    Session.Clear();
    Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
}
```

NOTE:(things working fine)

1.login working sucessfully

2.logout working sucessfully

3.back button is disabled once loggedout(not going on admin.aspx)

Issue:

When logged in i.e. on admin.aspx ,on clicking back button it redirects to home.aspx which i don't want. i expect it to remain on same `admin.aspx`

Comment: *i click back button* Which back button? browser or do you have any back button in your application? make it clear

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you click back button in the admin page, we understand what you don't want to, but what do you expect ?

Comment: its the back button of the browser... i expect it to remain on same admin.aspx page after clicking on browser's back button.... @mybirthname

Comment: @mybirthname, *but what do you expect* OP want to stay on same page. may be!

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript

Comment: With demo : http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Disable-Browser-Back-Button-Functionality-using-JavaScript.aspx

Comment: The thing is that if you went from A to B and press back, the expected behavior would be go back to A, or would you like your user to never be able to go back?

Comment: i want him to go back, but only on logout! @r1verside

Comment: why my code in Page_Load on home.aspx not working??

Answer (score 1):

ok.. finally trying all your solutions..this code worked on adding in my masterpage (in head tags)

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >

function preventBack(){window.history.forward();}
setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
window.onunload=function(){null};

</script>
```

[full details on this page](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Disable-Browser-Back-Button-Functionality-using-JavaScript.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can push the Window History forward to prevent the back button. This has work for me in most cases.  Include this JavaScript on your Admin.aspx page.

```
$(function() {
    window.history.forward();
});
```