# How to disable or override the back button using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to over ride the default action of the back button for my mobile website. If a pop up is there, I need to close it instead of going back to history. If no pop up is there, then back button behaves like normal.I'm using react.

Comment: This question has been asked a million times and the answer always includes. "Don't do that.".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to stop browser back button using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript)

Comment: You are probably looking for something like this: http://html5demos.com/history - give the popup its own point in the client browser's history.

Comment: These comments are perhaps a bit knee-jerk, and the duplicate is not very relevant. If I open a popup, I would certainly expect the back button to go back on an Android web browser.

Comment: Are you talking about a real popup, or a modal window?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_popstate_event) and create a new 'point' or state in the client browser's history whenever the popup pop's up:

```js
let button = document.getElementById("button");
let popup = document.getElementById("popup");

button.addEventListener("click", event => {
  state = {}; // TODO: define useful state
  history.pushState(state, "popup");
  popup.classList.toggle("hidden");
});

window.addEventListener("popstate", event => {
  popup.classList.toggle("hidden"); // TODO: evaluate `event.state`
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Open popup!</button>
<div id="popup" class="hidden">I am the popup. Close me by clicking your browser's 'back' button.</div>
```

Of course, as your application becomes more complex, you would want to use a [routing library](https://medium.com/@dabit3/beginner-s-guide-to-react-router-53094349669) which handles this for you.