# Disable browser back button is not working in javascript jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am trying to stop browser back button but my code is not working when click back button it can directly going back how can i do this i am calling ajax not using any form type tag

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
 function preventBack() { window.history.forward(); }
            setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
            window.onunload = function () { null };
    </script>
```

I have separate .js files i added in that document.ready function() but it's not working

Comment: You can't, if browsers allowed scripts to disable history navigation it would result in terrible experiences for the user.

Comment: But how can i disable browser back button

Comment: Like I said: you can't

Comment: Hi @MikaelLennholm, I added previous page to this code it's working.

Comment: It only works when going back to a history entry that was pushed by you or that represents a fragment on the same page. If the user is going back to a different page there's nothing you can do to prevent that.

Comment: Disabling back button is bad when you consider UX, but you can prevent the browser from caching the pages though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to stop browser back button using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript)