# How can I disable back button on the browser with vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My vue component like this :

```
<template>
    <span class="rating">
        ...
    </span>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            'star': null
        }, 
        ...
    }
</script>
```

If the component is running I want to disable button back in the browser. So the user can not go back to the previous page

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you using vue-router? Because it has guards that can allow you to not let the user go back using the browser's back button.

Comment: @Potray, It seems not. I just want to disable the button back on certain pages only. Not all pages

Comment: @SuccessMan how do you navigate to these components where you want to disable the back button...using `<router-link>` or programmatic navigation?

Comment: @Vamsi Krishna, In every browser there is a button back in the form of back icon. I want to disable it

Comment: @SuccessMan i understood that but disabling back button is not perfect ...see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript  insread you can use `replace` while navigation to these components so that the navigation will not leave a history record.

Comment: You can't disable browser buttons, or any other buttons that not in your site.

Answer (score 2):

Try this script, by adding in your html file, where you creat vue instance

```
history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
window.onpopstate = function () {
    history.go(1);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this code whenever url changes. It will counteract user's back action

`window.history.forward(1)`