# Handling Back Button from browser in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

After logging into my Dashboard component, I don`t want the user to go back to my login page by using back button in the browser.

I`m not using Redux but only React.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to stop browser back button using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript)

Comment: Why not redirect the user to the `Dashboard` component if the user is already logged in, in the `Login` component?

Comment: what is expected behaviour when user clicks back button?

Comment: Redirecting it to the same page.

Answer (score 4):

I think this will help, if the user is logged in then stay on the same page.

```
if(loggedIn) {
  history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
  window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  history.go(1);
  };
}
```

Comment: componentDidMount() {
    const { loggedIn } = this.state;
    const { history, location } = window;
    if (loggedIn) {
      history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
      window.onpopstate = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        history.go(1);
      };
    }
  }

Comment: for me it goes back then comes back to current page

Answer (score 1):

I prefere using my custom hook to intercept browser's back navigation:

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

// Intercepts browser's Navigate Back event
export const useNavigateBack = (callback: Function): void => {
  const isInitialMount = useRef(true);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isInitialMount.current) {
      isInitialMount.current = false;
      
      window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
        window.history.pushState(null, '', document.URL);
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        callback();
      }, false);
    } else {
       // In my special case this fix was needeed:
       // window.history.pushState(null, '', document.URL);
    }
  }, [callback]);
}
```

And now I can call use useNavigateBack([my custom back navigation handler]) inside my component.