# Need to open link in new tab and close current tab with one click

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I find myself in need of a script to (1) open a link in a new tab and (2) close the current tab so the back button cannot be used to see the website that was previously being viewed. This is a security feature for a site, and unfortunately I'm at a complete loss. Nothing I've tried works and I don't know where to begin. This is likely very simple and is staring me in the face, but I don't normally find myself needing to use java for anything. Any ideas?

Comment: generally, javascript can only close a window/tab that was opened by javascript in the first place - so, (if I'm right) you wont be able to do what you want

Comment: `but I don't normally find myself needing to use java for anything` - you mean javascript, because java is nothing to do with it

Answer (score 0):

Its impossible, but as found in this thread [how to stop browser back button using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript) you can prevent users from going back.

Theres a JS bin with an example

Edit - Please bear in mind the warning **'It is generally a bad idea overriding the default behavior of web browser.'**