# React-Router: MemoryHistory

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history

So I've recently started playing around with `createMemoryHistory` because I'm building an app that'll be rendered inside an iframe. Fortunately, click on the UI buttons, I'm able to navigate around without modifying the url. However, when I click the "<-" (back) button in the browser, it modifies my url to the current path. Is there a way I can disable this s.t. clicking the back button doesn't change the url path but still maintains its behavior?

Thanks for your help!

```
//history.js
import createMemoryHistory from "history/createMemoryHistory";

const history = createMemoryHistory();

export default history;
```

I'm modifying history by doing `history.push(something)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep the url the same while still fire the history `back` behavior, you will probably need to override the default behavior of the browser back button with your desired behavior.

This link([how to stop browser back button using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript)) contains discussions on ways to achieve that. However, note that overriding default browser behavior possess certain risks and is not encouraged.