# How to disable back button navigation of browser ( asp.net mvc or jquery)

Tags: javascript

I have requirement to disable page back navigation of the browser..Can Any one please help me to achieve these through javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to stop browser back button using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Its a client side behavior , you can achieve it using `javascript` as the following :

```
history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
window.onpopstate = function () {
    history.go(1);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         function disablePrev() { window.history.forward() }
         window.onload = disablePrev();
         window.onpageshow = function(evt) { if (evt.persisted) disableBack() }
      });
```