# How to catch back button in vueJS

Tags: vue.js

We are trying that when opening a menu, and clicking back in the browser, the menu will close and WILL NOT go back.
How can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript

Comment: you can also use Vue router to help implement methods on navigation https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html

Comment: Open The Close menu? Or Close?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle on browser back button click event in Vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58950351/how-to-handle-on-browser-back-button-click-event-in-vuejs)