# How to handle on browser back button click event in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

In Vue component, I want to handle on browser back event like this:

```
mounted() {
  if ([browser back]) {
    console.log("browser back button clicked")
  } else {
    console.log("stay here")
  }
}
```

To handle browser back event, I found `window.onpopstate` function but I don't know how to put it inside the `if` statement.

Can you tell me what should I do on this case? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to put inside an if statement. The event handler is sort of an "if statement".

See this example:

```js
mounted() {
   // if back button is pressed
   window.onpopstate = function(event) {
     alert("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
   };
}
```

Comment: But in not browser back case, how can i handle this?

Comment: When in normal mode (before back pressed) you can add any code to mounted then override it in `onpopstate`. Are you checking for hash changes in url?