# Close the modal by back button(Browser) without route change

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, angular2-routing

I saw recent answers,but none satisfied this [Ngx-bootstrap Modal](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals)
with the close button problem. 
I used canDeactivate to not to change the route when modal is on open

> Here What i"ve done

this openModal is to  open the modal here a isModalOpen  is set to false on close but "Globally i initialized it with true"

```
openModal(msg, isVideoPhoto: boolean, isVideo: boolean) {
if (isVideo !== undefined) {
  this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(msg);

}
if (isVideoPhoto !== undefined) {
  this.modalService.config.backdrop = false;
}

const _combine = combineLatest(

  this.modalService.onHide,
  this.modalService.onHidden
).subscribe(() => this.changeDetection.markForCheck());
this.subscriptions.push(
  this.modalService.onHide.subscribe((reason: string) => {
    const _reason = reason ? `, dismissed by ${reason}` : '';
    console.log(`onHide event has been fired${_reason}`);
    this.isModalOpen = false;
  })
);
this.subscriptions.push(
  this.modalService.onHidden.subscribe((reason: string) => {
    const _reason = reason ? `, dismissed by ${reason}` : '';
    console.log(`onHidden event has been fired${_reason}`);
    this.unsubscribe();
  })
);

this.subscriptions.push(_combine);
}
```

This is for closing modal

```
closeModal(){
this.isModalOpen=false;
this.modalRef.hide();
 }
```

canDeactivate:

```
canDeactivate(){
return this.isModalOpen;
}
```

This class extends a class which contains openModal(),closeModal(),canDeactivate().

```
export class modalClose implements CanDeactivate<DynamicContentComponent>{
 canDeactivate(component: DynamicContentComponent,  route: 
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> | 
   boolean {
   console.log("canDeactivate");
  return component.canDeactivate();
  }
  }
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
{ 
path: ":ctype/:termid",   
component: DynamicContentComponent,
canDeactivate:[modalClose]
}
```

I want to close the modal with the back button of browser without any route change and after modal closed route wants to change on back button press...!

Comment: I recommend you to read this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript

Comment: No i want page not to reload

Comment: this is not my expected answer

Comment: I understand that you didn't properly read answers, you can edit code on browser back button for given answers.

Comment: ok i saw that,but how it works when modal opened

Comment: also using typescript