# Is there any way to make browser back button invisible or in inactive state using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do an app where onclick on home button it comes to home page,but i want to make browser back button invisible or in hidden state using javascript .Is there any way to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to stop browser back button using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript)

Comment: You cannot make it invisible nor disable it. You can just alert.

Comment: No, thankfully not.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to make a site full of annoying ads and trying to prevent users from leaving.

Comment: @K.P. maybe, but maybe he / she just wants to prevent users from navigating using the back button to keep internal states of the wepapp

Answer (score 0):

> window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "Your work will be lost."; };

will at least provide a warning, but it is not guaranteed because all browsers behave differently.

More information can be found here,
[how to stop browser back button using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript)