# Azure B2C Getting 400 BadRequest when SignUp using SignInSignup UserFlow

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Can anyone help me in resolving the error like why i am getting **400 BadRequest** when i click on **SignUp** **button** which uses a SignInSignUp userflow.

**Steps to produce this issue:**

1. Open two same login pages in two different tabs.
2. After that enter credentials on first tab and clicked on signin button which uses the same 
   SignInSignUp userflow.
3. At the same time i clicked on SignUp button on second tab which leads to 400 BadRequest.

[UserFlow Example](https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Custom_SignIn_SignUp_UserFlow/api/CombinedSigninAndSignup/unified?local=signup&csrf_token=UihthdoteqNJcElkalFOWDJxYW54YTVVWDB5dGVVODBmRUNOV1liZVA4aGdFVERTZnZtdXRxcDFVaHRXSzFFMS9tUVRKeVBBUlF6TWpUTjBqYkE9PTsyMDIwLTA1yuyuwsLTA1VDA1OjM0OjE4LjkwMDE2NzVaO21DdGprOTRpOHhTQjNjVHBTdzFhQnc9PTt7Ik9yY2hlc3RyYXRpb25TdGVwIjoxfQ==&tx=StateProperties=eyJUSUQiOiI1Y2ZkOWMxMS04OGRiLTQyMTQtOGM3OC0wYjFiZmI3YzAzYTUifQ&p=B2C_1_Custom_SignIn_SignUp_UserFlow)

**Screenshot Attached Below:**

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I have a bit different behaviour in a custom sign-in/sign-up policy. For me it returns to step 1 when clicking signup in the first one. I'm guessing it has something to do with cookies that the page uses as those would be shared across tabs. Maybe the CSRF prevention cookie gets changed by the second tab and so the first one won't work?

Comment: It  is a common scenario to prevent back button after sign up
e.g. "Navigation backwards after sign ups and purchases is disabled. Please use top site navigation instead" in a toast notification.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-can-i-stop-the-browser-back-button-using-javascript#comment124995548_34337617

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the same browser twice, once you sign in to the site, I'm pretty sure you get an auth token, with the associated cookie. your browser is now "logged in" so if you open a second same browser window or tab, and click sign up, it probably sees that you already have a logged in session cookie for that url and sends that and the server side is confused. I'm not quite sure why you would want to do that though. 
if you need to I would probably open an incognito window when starting the browser for the second "load" of the site to ensure you're not sending the same cookie to the signup page.

Comment: original question is how to handle the above-mentioned situation sometimes user open multiple links of SSO application and login with one tab and other tab remain as it is because it was opened before login and then user hit on signup link and fall into bad request