# How can I disable browser go to previous page when making HTML form.submit()?

Tags: javascript, html

Please see this minimum example

When using `location.href` to navigate to a new page, I can easily go to previous thanks to the browser.

```html
<button>Can Go To Previous Page</button>

<script>
  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
    window.location.href = "https://google.com";
  });
</script>
```

And I can easily disable the behavior simply using `location.replace`

```html
<button>Can Not Go Back Anymore!</button>

<script>
  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
    window.location.replace("https://google.com");
  });
</script>
```

Now, how can I make `form.submit()` acts like `location.replace`?

Because you can still go back to the previous page when you submitting a form.

Is it possible to do this?

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label>
    First name:
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" />
  </label>
  <button>Submit, Can still go back here</button>
</form>

<script>
  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const form = document.querySelector("form");

    form.submit();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forms have a default behavior which causes them to submit the values of the form to the endpoint of the `action` attribute, or reload the form on the same page. The former action causes a redirect from the backend and therefor you've navigated forwards and can now go back.

You can use AJAX to manually submit the form with JavaScript and disable the default behavior. First, listen for the `submit` event on the form itself, not the button. A button without a specified `type` attribute will automatically be a submit button if it is inside a form.

Then immediately call [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to stop the form from submitting. Now you can create your own submitting behavior.

Extract the values from the form with a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) constructor. This will return you an iterable object in which all input fields are stored in pairs of `name` and `value`.

Now use the [`Fetch API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to send the `FormData` object to your endpoint, which you've specified in your `action` attribute, and send it with a `POST` method. Make sure that your backend also expects this method.

Then after the request has finished use `location.replace()` to change the URL to your liking.

The example below contains all that I've described here above. Check it out and please let me know if you have any questions.

```
const form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", async event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(form)
  const response = await fetch(form.action, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  }
  if (response.ok) {
    location.replace('yourredirecturl')
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a simple workaround that looks like this:

```
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); validateMyForm();">
```

Then you'd need to write the `validateMyForm` function to handle the form and redirect the user.

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario you can simple delete browser history on action_page.php while loading

**browser.history.deleteAll();**

FYI :- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/history/deleteAll

Comment: I think this is browser extensions API?