# How to take keyboard input in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to take keyboard input in JavaScript, where arrow keys, when pressed, will result in the change in shape of a particular shape. How do I take the input of any of the keys in JavaScript?

Comment: Is this to be done in a browser? If so you can capture keyboard events.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can do this by [registering an *event handler*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) on the document or any element you want to observe keystrokes on and examine the [key related properties of the event object](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html).

Example that works in FF and Webkit-based browsers:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 37) {
        alert('Left was pressed');
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 39) {
        alert('Right was pressed');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PQVnT/2/)

Comment: theres anything that I can do to capture Backspace but prevent browser to "Go Back" ?

Comment: @Vitimtk: Sorry, I don't really have time now, but have a look at these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+disable+backspace+navigation

Comment: Using event.preventDefault() is probably what you want. As the name suggests, it prevents whatever the default behavior would be for a given event, in this case a backspace keyboard event. This goes into more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495219/how-can-i-prevent-the-backspace-key-from-navigating-back

Comment: keyCode is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Answer (score 22):

You should register an event handler on the window or any element that you want to observe keystrokes on, and use the standard [key values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values) instead of keyCode.
This modified code from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) will respond to keydown when the left, right, up, or down arrow keys are pressed:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.defaultPrevented) {
    return; // Do nothing if the event was already processed
  }

  switch (event.key) {
    case "ArrowDown":
      // code for "down arrow" key press.
      break;
    case "ArrowUp":
      // code for "up arrow" key press.
      break;
    case "ArrowLeft":
      // code for "left arrow" key press.
      break;
    case "ArrowRight":
      // code for "right arrow" key press.
      break;
    default:
      return; // Quit when this doesn't handle the key event.
  }

  // Cancel the default action to avoid it being handled twice
  event.preventDefault();
}, true);
// the last option dispatches the event to the listener first,
// then dispatches event to window
```

Comment: I seem to be able to detect normal alpha-numeric keys, but not arrow keys (Safari / MacOS).

Comment: I have to use this on Chrome and this is extremely amazing. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

If you are doing this in a browser, you can capture keyboard events.

- keydown
- keypress
- keyup

Can all be listened to on HTML nodes in most browsers.

Webkit also supports...

- textInput

See for more details .. http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Answer (score 4):

Since event.keyCode is deprecated, I found the event.key useful in javascript. Below is an example for getting the names of the keyboard keys pressed (using an input element). They are given as a KeyboardEvent key text property:

```js
function setMyKeyDownListener() {
    window.addEventListener(
      "keydown",
      function(event) {MyFunction(event.key)}
    )
}

function MyFunction (the_Key) {
    alert("Key pressed is: "+the_Key);
}
```

```css
html { font-size: 4vw; background-color: green; color: white; padding: 1em; }
```

```html
<body onload="setMyKeyDownListener()">
    <div>
        <input id="MyInputId">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [JQuery keydown](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/) event.

```
$(document).keypress(function(){
    if(event.which == 70){  //f
        console.log("You have payed respect");
    }
});
```

In JS; keyboard keys are identified by [Javascript keycodes](http://gcctech.org/csc/javascript/javascript_keycodes.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access keyboard state at any point in time, you can use this code to create & maintain a set of the keys that are currently pressed:

```
let keyboard = new Set();
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {keys.add(e.key)})
window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {keys.delete(e.key)})
```

Then you can access this information like so:

```
if (keyboard.size == 0) { console.log("no keys pressed") }
if (keyboard.has("e")) { console.log("key e is pressed") }
for (let k of keyboard.values()) { console.log("key "+k+" is pressed") }
```