# How to handle console keyboard input in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am making a simple text adventure using javascript and I need a way to make the player be able to write 1, 2, 3 or 4 when asked in order to select the corresponding choices. How do I do this? `readline()` and `console.read()` don't work.

I am not using a website. I need it in the console.

Comment: Forget about the console... Use [window.prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.prompt).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416505/how-to-take-keyboard-input-in-javascript

Comment: If this is in a browser just use a textbox...

Comment: You can also use a standard text input, or a jQuery dialog, or an event listener, etc...

Comment: You can always run it on http://jsfiddle.net/ and use the tools previously suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == EVENTCODE) {
        //action
    }

});
```

in the place of EVENTCODE place numbers:

```
48 = 0
49 = 1 
50 = 2 
51 = 3 
52 = 4 
53 = 5 
54 = 6 
55 = 7 
56 = 8 
57 = 9,
```

Comment: Why not just finish the example by adding the numbers (at least partially)?

Comment: How am I supposed to use it if I have no document? I am not using a website for this.

Comment: How am I supposed to know that?

Comment: @user1571481: so in what environment is this running? Did you not think that information might be of use to the people trying to help you out?

Comment: @David Thomas I want to run it in repl.it javascript interpreter