# Function works with text input but not numerical input

Tags: javascript, html, function, input, nan

I have a JavaScript function that clears a text input if an alphabet character is typed into it.

```js
input = document.getElementById('inf');
input.onkeyup = function() {
  value = input.value;
  truth = isNaN(value);
  if (truth) {
    input.value = '';
  }

};
```

```css
input {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='inf' />Numbers Only
<br />Type a number in, and it stays. Put a letter in, and the input clears itself
```

The problem is, this does not work when the input type is set to number, as evidenced by the below sample.

```js
input=document.getElementById('inf');
input.onkeyup=function(){
  value=input.value;
  truth=isNaN(value);
  if(truth){
    input.value='';
  }
  
};
```

```css
input{
  border:2px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<input type='number' id='inf'/>
<br />
As you can see, it doesnt work anymore.
```

My question is twofold:

1) Why does it work with a text input but not a number input?

2)Is there an easy fix? I need it as a number input, so that must stay the same.

Please Javascript answers only. No jQuery.

Comment: The htlm5 number input (as the name suggests) is meant to only accept numeric values. It will ignore any non number character, without altering the value entered so far. If you want the input to clear when a letter is entered (assuming that you have a very good reason to want that behavior), you have to start from a text input and listen for a key events. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416505/how-to-take-keyboard-input-in-javascript (as you did)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number inputs don't allow non-numeric data, so this will always be false:

```
truth= isNaN(value);
```

Instead, you could check if the key pressed is a digit or a decimal:

```js
input=document.getElementById('inf');
input.onkeyup=function(e) {
  if(!/[\d\.]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) {
    input.value='';
  }
};
```

```html
<input type='number' id='inf'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

When input type is number, it returns null if there is a non-number character in the text.
So

```
"abc123" = ""  
"123abc" = ""  
"123" = "123"  


isNaN(null) is false.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just check for `blank` along with your `isNaN` check

`var truth = isNaN(value) || value==='';`

Since the input type=number will convert any non numeric to blank