# How to make a sound respond to a key press in js html canvas?

Tags: javascript, audio, canvas

I am making a canvas, one where you are a little ship and you shoot little pixels to destroy other little pixel ships. I want to make it so that when you press the key that would make the ship shoot, it would also play a little "pew" sound. I have no idea how to add sounds or images for that matter. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried [searching Stack Overflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript) There are [plenty of resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416505/how-to-take-keyboard-input-in-javascript) that will help you.

Comment: Canvas does not include a sound api, you would need to use the audio tag in standard html for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is an audio tag in HTML. Put any sounds you'll be using within the tag like so:

```
<audio>
<source id="pew" src="pew.mp3"></source>
</audio>
```

In Javascript, there is a standard method called play():

```
function playSound(){
    var sound = document.getElementById("pew");
    sound.play();
}
```

Call the function either in HTML or with JQuery:

```
<input type="button" value="pew pew pew" onClick="playSound()">
```