# Can't capture delete key pressed in jQuery

Tags: jquery, events

I'm executing the following code as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935655/how-to-trap-the-backspace-key-using-jquery).

```
$("#textBox").on("keyup", function (event) {
  foo(event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 64);
});

function foo(special) {
  console.log(special);
}
```

For <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> it works like a charm producing *true*. However, <kbd>Del</kbd> produces *false*. What's up with that?!

Comment: Isn't the delete key 46, not 64?

Comment: @StevenVondruska If you add an answer I will give you +1. :-) I respect you because you was so fast!

Comment: Side note: you should use `event.which` instead of `event.keyCode`, it normalizes `keyCode` and `charCode`

Comment: Try using keydown event

Comment: @Johnツ eh, I should have posted as an answer instead. But Avitus did answer the question and no need for me to do the rep grab. Thanks for the shout out though!

Comment: @billyonecan Good point. Add it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: I posted the answer about the same exact time you commented so feel free to answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the keycode for delete is 46 not 64.

See: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: Hrmp... Well - what the {your favorite profanity here}! I meant 64. Can't the stupid computer understand what I mean?! I was about to yell at the idiot that posted 64 in the question I linked to. But apparently someone tries to make me look dumb and changed that just now. It **was definitely** 64 before... (The bucket of shame over my head - pounding hard on it with a hammer.)