# put dash after every n character during input from keyboard and edit exact number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I found this tutorial from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852888/put-dash-after-every-n-character-during-input-from-keyboard).It would appear like this:35-354-55444-54-54324..It works fine but when i try to edit any code it is not working correctly.when i press backspace it takes automatically number.Here is my code:

```js
function format(input, format, sep) {
  var output = "";
  var idx = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < format.length && idx < input.length; i++) {
    output += input.substr(idx, format[i]);
    if (idx + format[i] < input.length) output += sep;
    idx += format[i];
  }

  output += input.substr(idx);
  return output;
}

$('.creditCardText').keyup(function() {
  var foo = $(this).val().replace(/-/g, ""); // remove hyphens
  // You may want to remove all non-digits here
  // var foo = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, "");

  if (foo.length > 0) {
    foo = format(foo, [2, 3, 5, 2, 5], "-");
  }

  $(this).val(foo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="creditCardText" maxlength="21" />
```

Comment: Please be clear about the problem you're facing. What is not working? Can you give an example?

Comment: This code is fully working but when i'm trying to edit any number its not working correctly.Suppose i have a number like '75-354-55444-54-54324' now i want to remove 7 using backspace and add 2 on the place of 7.This is not working here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is, as I understand it, the string gets reformatted when you delete a number somewhere, plus the cursor jumps to the end. This makes it hard to do quick and meaningful edits.

I suggest to [trap the `backspace`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935655/how-to-trap-the-backspace-key-using-jquery) and `delete` keys and skip the string reformatting process in that case. This can have side effects but should suit your needs.

```js
function format(input, format, sep) {
  var output = "";
  var idx = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < format.length && idx < input.length; i++) {
    output += input.substr(idx, format[i]);
    if (idx + format[i] < input.length) output += sep;
    idx += format[i];
  }

  output += input.substr(idx);
  return output;
}

$('.customerNumberText').keyup(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 8   //alert('backspace')
  || e.keyCode == 46) //alert('delete')
  return;


  var foo = $(this).val().replace(/-/g, ""); // remove hyphens
  // You may want to remove all non-digits here
  // var foo = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, "");

  if (foo.length > 0) {
    foo = format(foo, [2, 3, 5, 2, 5], "-");
  }

  $(this).val(foo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="customerNumberText" maxlength="21" />
```