# Saving work before new URL in Address Bar Executed

Tags: google-chrome

I have a web page where people can go and design things, let's say furniture layout.  There are buttons on the page to save the work, but I don't have any protection if someone just goes up and puts a new URL in the Address bar. Then the browser (say Chrome 34.0) throws out all the current work and loads the new page.  How can I force Chrome to open the new URL in a new tab, or at least catch the exit from the current page so I can save the work for the user?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warn user before leaving page with unsaved changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317273/warn-user-before-leaving-page-with-unsaved-changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a javascript popup that runs when the user has modifyed the work with this line:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){ return 'All unsaved Work will be lost.' }
```

The popup will look something like this

```
Confirm Navigation

All unsaved Work will be lost.

Press OK to continue, or Cancel to stay on the current page.
```

Use this line to prevent the popup once the user saves:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```