# How to disable back and refresh button in browser using php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Want to disable back and refresh button for a website in php using codeigniter.

whenever the person click on browser back button it should not be able to go on the page he visited before.

and does not reload that page once loaded.

hey its not for static page its for dynamic page . attending question on online test. please understand that

Comment: Afraid you can't do that.

Comment: And you shouldn't do it. Don't mess with people's browsers!

Comment: You can't.  Amd you should not want to

Comment: Imagine you visit a website and this is what happens to you... Would you like that?

Comment: any option had to do not reload that page?

Comment: hey @Marc@ mind it below what i m said. its not for static page . attending  question on online test. please understand that

Comment: Better to use Javascript for this that can stop back button.If you want that i can suggest you.

Comment: @Yuvaraj Are you looking for a solution for preventing double form submit?

Comment: May be this link can help you http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/PHP/Q_21070840.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that. Except you may show an alert to user, when he tries to close window.

About the alert:
[Warn user before leaving web page with unsaved changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317273/warn-user-before-leaving-web-page-with-unsaved-changes)

Answer (score 0):

That's imho not possible, and it's good so :) If you want, that your users don't use the back key, write this down as a warning message or something else :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out Iam not sure this is your actual issue but maybe it will help you out.
[Preventing Double submit on refresh/back](http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/4131929.htm)