# Is it possible to catch browser close cross mark and ctrl w?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to catch browser close cross mark and ctrl w ??

I was trying with various thing as

**// 1st option**

```
 window.onunload = function (e) {
// Firefox || IE
e = e || window.event;
var y = e.pageY || e.clientY;

if (y < 0) {
alert("close");
}
else {
alert("refresh");
}
}
```

**// 2nd option**

```
<body onunload="myFunction()">

function myFunction()
{
    alert('sss');
}
```

**// 3rd option**

```
$( window ).unload(function() {

  alert('window unload');

});
```

But nothing has working for me (Measn these alerts weren't coming when i click on **cross mark button** on browser or used **Ctrl + W** )

Could anybody please let em know how to resolve this ??

Comment: Could you detect the mouse going to the X? Idk, i don't think you can intercept browser actions with jQuery

Comment: is it possible with javascript ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warn user before leaving web page with unsaved changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317273/warn-user-before-leaving-web-page-with-unsaved-changes)

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript detect browser close tab/close browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `onbeforeunload`:

```
var myFunction = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    var message = "exit message";

    // For IE6-8 and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (e) 
    {
        e.returnValue = message;
    }

    // For Chrome, Safari, IE8+ and Opera 12+
    return message;
}
window.onbeforeunload = myFunction;
```

Comment: Thank you very much , This is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p586bL44/ , how  to avoid this popup initaily during page load (I mean i want this popup only when user wants to exit the browser .)

Comment: I don't get this message when the page loads, only when I exit? It's also not necessary to include that body tag in there: https://jsfiddle.net/yb00ktc8/

Comment: thank you , the only other issue i see that , the confirmation pop up is showing a different message than whats present in the function

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e) {
    var message = "Why are you leaving?";
    e.returnValue = message;
    return message;
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/XZAWS/308/**

Comment: Thank you is it possible to show this confirmation box only when the user tries to exit the browser

Comment: @PreethiJain put it in a index.html file and you will see that it only pops up as the user closes the tab/browser