# How to disable/override "Do you want to leave this site?" alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've a form in a pop-up, which is loaded by AJAX call. It is built using `form_for` tag of RoR. Even if I don't modify any field in it and try to navigate to another page, following alert is shown by chrome.

[image]

I want to **disable** this alert box. Is it possible? If yes, how?

I've already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317273/warn-user-before-leaving-web-page-with-unsaved-changes), but it is not valid anymore.

Following are the environment settings,

```
Ruby version = 1.9.3
Rails version = 3.1.4
Chrome version = 52
jQuery version = 1.10.2
```

Comment: How did you do you call to this alert?

Comment: I'm not calling it. Chrome is by default throwing this error. It comes when I'm opening the form, otherwise everything is going great.

Comment: This isn't Chrome, it's something else (that is telling Chrome to do this), possibly rails-ujs, though I don't remember if that existed in Rails 3 (which is really old at this point) or whether this would have been default configuration. Basically, there should be some gem or something that is doing this, and you can probably tell it not to, but without more information I'm not able to guess what's doing it, and you probably do not just want to do something like blanket intercept all beforeunload and cancel them because that could affect other things.

Answer (score 18):

Alert is displayed because somewhere on your code, you are overriding the window before unload event, and when you try to close the window, the event fires.
Try disallow this event putting up this on your code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

Comment: but this will remove all the `onbeforeunload` events. I want to run code which I've specified in `onbeforeunload` event, but not chrome's version

Comment: Can't you override that function?

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload = yourCustomFunction;` should work

Answer (score 2):

Set it to an empty function:

`window.onbeforeunload = () => {}`

Answer (score 2):

You can hook in any other function inside the `beforeunload` handler:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e){
    yourCustomFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your `form` tag inside `div` like this:

`<div class="col-xs-12 no-padding"><form role="form" class="form-horizontal pad10-top" id="" onSubmit="return false;">
...</form></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well.

`$(window).off('beforeunload');`

Answer (score 0):

adding this line got me through

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) { return true; });
```