# How do I disable the "Leave page" confirmation dialog in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firefox, onbeforeunload, confirm

I have the following code in my `Vue` application for detecting when the user closes the tab:

```
onBeforeUnload() {
  window.onbeforeunload = null;
  return undefined;
}
```

Disabling the "Leave page" confirmation dialog works in Chrome, but not on Firefox. Why is that? How do I disable the confirmation dialog on Firefox?

**Edit 1:** Adding and removing `beforeunload` listeners

```
created() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.onBeforeUnload);
},
beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.onBeforeUnload);
}
```

Comment: Something may be adding the confirmation with `window.addEventListener()` rather than assigning to `window.onbeforeunload`. You can't remove that unless you know the name of the function that was added.

Comment: You can overwrite it by assigning an empty function to it

Comment: @Barmar I have added an edit to my post that has the `addEventListener` for my `Vue` application.

Comment: I think that should work.

Comment: @Barmar It works for Chrome but not Firefox.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable/override "Do you want to leave this site?" alert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723567/how-to-disable-override-do-you-want-to-leave-this-site-alert)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I've looked at those answers before, but I managed to figure out how to fix the problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing my `onBeforeUnload` method to this fixed the problem:

```
onBeforeUnload(e) {
  window.onbeforeunload = () => {};
  delete e.returnValue;
}
```