# On browser refresh stop propogation without a prompt

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In below code,

```
$window.onbeforeunload = function reloadFunc(event) {
                     // Check if form is dirty, prompt the user and cancel event
                     scope.dirtyCheckWarning(event);                        
                };
```

I am figuring out how to cancel the event and stop propogation.

Comment: You can't block user from closing a page. Even if you could, I (as the user) would have an annoying experience, and would never open your site again.

Comment: You can give a look in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7317311/6188402)