# How to warn unsaved changes when leaving a page in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have several forms and input fields that I use in my Customize.vue file. I have to detect any unsaved changes and trigger a notification.

```
methods: {
    alertChange() {
        this.$notify.make('You have unsaved changes!', 'warning');
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using vue router?

Comment: Hi. I just learned about vue-router a while ago. I tried using `beforeRouteLeave` that contains `alert('Unsaved changes')` but it doesn't get triggered.

Comment: Can you share demo code if possible?

Comment: I literally just added this after `methods`, `beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) { alert('Unsaved changes'); }`

Comment: @Bargain23 wouldn't your solution alert the user even if there are no changes to save? You should implement dirty flags to keep track of changes, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7317311/583895) (although it's vanilla javascript, the concepts for vue.js are similar)