# Disable Browser Back Button and Solve refresh error in JSP

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, browser

I want to disable browser back button. So I used below code

```
  <script type = "text/javascript" >
        history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
        window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {           
            history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
        });
</script>
```

It was disable browser back button but Afert submit a page and refresh that page there was a error. page not found.

Comment: _"disable browser back button"_ - **do not do this**. Instead use the unload event and present the user with an option to cancel. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317273/warn-user-before-leaving-web-page-with-unsaved-changes

Comment: Honestly, I see no way disabling the back button could serve **_ANY_** legitimate functionality at all. You either are about to make a _very_ bad design choice or you are trying to create one of those scam-sites that try to stop you from leaving.

Comment: **give me good solution for disable**

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution https://codepen.io/dhavalt10/pen/rGLBzB (not mine) while investigating this problem and worked fine for me. I tested on the latest Chrome, Edge, IE and Firefox.

Basically the js code force the browser to keep on the same page always and Refresh also worked fine.

```
history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
window.onpopstate = function () {
    history.go(1);
};
```