# jQuery or Javascript raise confirm() when back button pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to raise a confirm() function when the user presses the back button in the browser. 
What is the event I should look for?
Inside this scope, what should I add to success:

```
    $(document).ready(function () { TODO}
```

I don't need to use jQuery, a Javascript solution also works for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warn user before leaving web page with unsaved changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317273/warn-user-before-leaving-web-page-with-unsaved-changes)