# Don't show redirect warning if variable is true

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, reload

I have some actions being performed on my website and I don't want people leaving or reloading accidentally before all actions are done. This is pretty straight forward but when all the actions are done I don't want them seeing the warning (I want them just to get redirected).

I followed [Warn user before leaving web page with unsaved changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317273/warn-user-before-leaving-web-page-with-unsaved-changes) and few others but that last part (no warning when everything is done, certain variable set to true).

So this is what I got:

Here the variable that was previously set gets the value true after all actions are done. (This works fine)

```
do_redirect = true;
window.location.href = "some url";
```

Now this is the part where I get the leave/reload warning:

```js
do_redirect = true;
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    if (do_redirect) {
        console.log("ITS TRUE")
        return undefined;
    }
    console.log(do_redirect);
    var confirmationMessage = 'If you leave, you are not going to be able to come back';

    (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
    return confirmationMessage; //Gecko + Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.
});
```

```html
<button onclick="do_redirect = false;">Create unsaved work</button>
<button onclick="do_redirect = true;">Save work</button><br/>
<button onclick="location.href = 'data:text/plain,You were redirected!';">Try leaving</button>
```

So the regular user leave/reload works perfectly but the problem occurs when I (the website) wants to redirect users to another page. I'm not sure what the problem here is.

Comment: What is the value of `do_redirect` when redirecting? Does the console log show?

Comment: Yes, it's true I checked it and the log shows as well

Comment: May you describe what happens when `do_redirect` is true?

Comment: When do_redirect is true I don't want users seeing the "Don't leave..." box. I want them to just be redirected

Comment: It's good you know what you want, but may you explain _what actually occurs_?

Comment: The problem I'm having now is that whether do_redirect is true or false the box pops up

Comment: That's probably because the `beforeunload` event listener still exists. You may need to remove the listener when `do_redirect` is made true

Comment: For example, `function enableLeave(){ onbeforeunload=function(){}; }` and `function disableLeave(){ onbeforeunload=function(){ return false; }; }`.  Those functions will enable and disable leaving.

Comment: Great, this works perfectly. Submit it as an answer if you want.