# How not to refresh the page when query parameters change?

Tags: javascript, html, unity-webgl

There is a Unity WebGL application on the page. You need to call a certain function when a page parameter changes, but not to update it, so that the changes only affect the application. Is this even possible?

I was trying to find information on this and came across ajax, but it didn't seem to me to be quite what I needed. I couldn't find any more information.

Comment: what is changing the url?

Comment: @epascarello, user

Comment: How is the user changing the URL? Are they clicking the address bar, changing what is typed there, then pressing Enter?

Comment: If the user edits the location bar and enters, the browser always refreshes with the new URL.

Comment: There has got to be an additional config parameter besides query params you could employ, dig into the docs.

Comment: @Quentin, that's right

Comment: @code, docs of what?

Comment: Whatever application you're using.

Comment: I don't think you can prevent the user from typing whatever they want into their location bar in their browser.

Comment: @code, it's my application, i make it

Comment: @mykaf, My goal is not to forbid the user to enter anything, my goal when the link changes is not to reload the page, but to affect the application

Comment: If the user "submits" the location bar, it's going to reload the page anyway. You can't stop that. But now you say "link" - what link do you mean?

Comment: link in the bar

Answer (score 1):

The user entering an address into their browser and loading a new page (even if is the same page) is an operation that happens outside of the web application. You cannot prevent it.

The closest you could come would be to [warn the user that they are leaving your app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7317311/19068) and offer them the opportunity to cancel navigation. They do not have to take it.

Comment: if i do server, that get queries and will handle it as I need to, it wil solve problem?

Comment: Your stated problem is that the page reloads if the user reloads the page. You can't prevent the user from doing that.