# DocuSign Embedded Signing - User Closes Browser Window

Tags: docusignapi

I am currently exploring embedded signing from within my application and the happy path works well.  End users are inherently unpredictable so have been testing some failure scenarios.

One of those is around recovering from a situation where Embedded Signing has loaded but the user then closes the browser window.

From within my application, how can I detect such a situation.  Is DocuSign able to send a webhook message when the session times out?  Or would I have to query DocuSign to determine what happened with the Embedded Signing session?

Comment: [Add an event listener for `beforeUnload`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7317311/11613622)

Comment: Would that work when DocuSign isn't being loaded within website?  The user gets directed to DocuSign and then upon completion is returned back to the form.

Answer (score 0):

If you launch the signing in another window you can use tequniues detailed in this thread - [Detect browser or tab closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing) to detect when the new tab/window is closed.

You could use an iframe inside your web application as well, then it cannot be closed, but your entire app can be closed.

Finally, yes, you can use a webhook to get events about the envelope, but a closer of the window is not one of these events, so you may have to make an API call yourself to check the status of the envelope.

Answer (score 0):

The embedded signing ceremony can also be configured to send a heartbeat (from the browser) to your app. See the [pingUrl](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createrecipient/#schema__recipientviewrequest_pingurl) attribute and pingFrequency