# Why react app shows alert in chrome to confirm reloading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

I have a react app created with create-react-app.

In package.json dependencies I have:

```
...
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-app-rewired": "2.2.1",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
...
```

in scripts I have:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run watch:css & react-app-rewired start",
    ...
```

In `config-overrides.js` file I have next:

```
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  config.plugins.push(
    new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
      languages: ['json', 'html']
    })
  );

  return config;
};
```

The problem is, whenever I change something in the code hot reloading is triggered, but in browser (chrome) it show me an alert to confirm that I want to reload the page.

[image]

Any idea why?

Comment: What kind of alert? Maybe you have some on unload event?

Comment: This happens when you have form fields which contain unsaved data. You can trigger this, see also this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317273/warn-user-before-leaving-web-page-with-unsaved-changes