# Triple (3) Equal Signs

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript === vs == : Does it matter which “equal” operator I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

I asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112127/prevent-backspace-from-navigating-back-with-jquery-like-googles-homepage) here and received a great answer as follows:

```
$(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
  if (e.which === 8 && !$(e.target).is("input, textarea") || $(e.target).is('[readonly]')) {
      e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Notice the three equal signs `===` in the if-statement. I have always thought you only needed two equal signs `==` for a javascript/jQuery if-statement. Is there any reason for the three?

**UPDATE**

Sorry for the duplicate question - I searched but didn't find any good questions. I guess I was using the wrong search terms.

Comment: I am guessing its checking absolute equality. Meaning, not just equal, but the same

Comment: This other question has a lot of information on the subject (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Comment: Stack Overflow's search feature cannot handle characters such as `=`, unfortunately. But Google does work: http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+javascript+%3D%3D%3D+vs+%3D%3D

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The triple equal sign in javascript means *equality without type coercion*.

For example:

```
1=="1"     // true, automatic type coercion
1==="1"    // false, not the same type.
```

Comment: JS true, false and equal in details: https://gist.github.com/romankierzkowski/9024908

Comment: +1 I think in terms of strongly typed languages - so the second example would throw an error. Still not used to this and been using javascript for a while now

Answer (score 14):

Three equal signs indicates both the value and type are equal.

Comment: I started to answer just like that, then figured this had to be a dupe, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)