# second if statement not working

Tags: javascript

In the below program i am using 3 if conditions, but the if statement in the middle doesn't works and last if statement works fine,when I change third if statement to second statement again second statement is not working properly.
Third if statement works fine

```
function calculate() {
    var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
    var discount = document.getElementById("discount").value;
    var tax = document.getElementById("tax").value;

    if((quantity && price ) != null) {
        amount = quantity * price;
        document.getElementById("amount").value = amount;
    } else {
        alert("price & tax required");
    }

    if(discount != null) {
        var discount_amount = (quantity*price*discount)/100;
        amount = (quantity*price) - discount_amount;
        document.getElementById("amount").value = amount;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("amount").value = quantity * price;
    }

    if(tax != null) {
        var tax_amount = (quantity*price*tax)/100;
        amount = (quantity*price) + tax_amount;
        document.getElementById("amount").value = amount;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("amount").value = quantity * price;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem? like, what is not working. What should it do, what isn't it doing? what does the js-console say ?

Comment: Can you put your HTML in your question too?

Comment: try document.write(discount) to see the value of the discount to make sure that isn't null

Comment: @StuiterSlurf please don't suggest `document.write()` as that will confuse the issue when it wipes the contents of the page.  `console.log()` is perfect for quick debugging.  I'd even prefer an `alert()` over `document.write()`!!!

Comment: Like Nina pointed out a string in Javascript is a string, a null is a different type.  Empty strings equal `""`, not null.  But if you do want empty strings to be null, you could also do -> `var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value || null`

Comment: @Keith Doh - my bad :)

Answer (score 2):

[`input.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) returns a string, which is never `null`, but it can be an empty string, like `''`.

Empty strings a converted to zero in numerical context. If that is not wanted, you need an explicit check, like

```
if (input.value === '') {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(discount != null)
```

discount will be empty string and not null check for:

```
 if(discount !== "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly check for null in any of your `if` tests, as zero values as well as undefioned

```
if (quantity && price) {
   // only want to come in here for non-zero values of both
}

if (discount) {
   // only interested in the discount for non-zero values
}

if (tax) {
  // only interested in non-zero values of tax
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> if(discount != null)

lets assume discount variable is empty string. What do you thnik about result ?

```
if(""!=null)
```

It will be `true`
What if your string comes fullfiled with some data

```
if("someData"!=null)
```

It will be `true`again.

I do not blame you. Javascript has some magical act in these kinds of situation.

In javascript, there is a lot of logic operation that can represent as `false` for if condition. Below code, all `if` statements return false

```
if(""){//code here}
if(null){//code here}
if(0){//code here}
```

A developer should not compare two different types like `null` and `string`.
Just in case, I advise you to avoid double equal sign `==`. Use triple `===` it is type-sensitive .
see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234575/triple-3-equal-signs)