# This condition will always return 'false' since the types '0' and '2' have no overlap

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am using vue class style component as following.

```
@Component()
export default class Transfer extends Vue {

  @Prop({ default: [] })
  buttonTexts!: [];
  
  get hasButtonTexts() {
    return this.buttonTexts.length === 2; // Here it gives error.
  }
  
}
```

and it shows error as below:

"This condition will always return 'false' since the types '0' and '2' have no overlap"

Is this a bug or I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: Hi There is nothing with Vue to do here, it's Javascript which creates error for you. Can you let me what is the value of `this.buttonTexts.length` and also it's type

Comment: what is `buttonTexts!` , why is there `!` ?

Comment: As per typescript it is of type array of never by default (never[]). when I do "any[]", then it works. so what is the issue with "never[]" ? So it was issue with never type. any works for me. so now issue is solved. now question is, why it is not working with never[]?

Comment: [3 = signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234575/triple-3-equal-signs)

Comment: @RadicalEdward - The `!` there is a *definite assignment assertion*. It tells TypeScript that `buttonTexts` is definitely assigned somewhere, even if TypeScript can't see that assignment.

Comment: @Luuk. triple equal still should work. as length is number and 2 is also number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the type you're giving `buttonTexts`: `[]`. That's an empty [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), not (just) an array. Empty tuples always have a `length` of `0`, and since `length` can't be any other number, the type of `length` is the literal type `0` rather than `number` (more below).

You almost certainly want `buttonTexts` to be an array of something. For instance, perhaps strings:

```
buttonTexts!: string[]
```

[Playground link to pared-down code showing the issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqBOYB2EBmBTe0DeAoX00ARgK4AuZA9krOgB5kQCEAXNANoC6A3AdHwHN0ZaAAtIAIXJUa9RgAoAlDj6F4wkvCTQyogJYQAdKQrVaDIyHRIBu6AF5H0AEzdoAenfQAEpnTQ9EQE9ADd0GEx4SnhDPgBfPlwEoA).

[Playground link to example fix](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqBOYB2EBmBTe0DeAoX00ARgK4AuZA9krOgB5kQCEAXNBGfAJZIDmA2gF0A3AWhje6MtAAWkAELkqNeowAUAShxjC8KSXhJoZGVwgA6UhWq0GFkOj4noAXjfQATMOgB6H9AAJTHRoLmleLgA3dBhMeEp4czEAXzFcVKA).

---

So what's going on with this `[]`? What's a tuple?

Basically, TypeScript lets you define types that are arrays with specific contents. For example: `[string]` is an array containing exactly one string. `[string, number]` is an array containing exactly two elements, the first one is a string, the second is a `number`. (This is handy for functions that return multiple things, like React's `useState`.) Similarly, `[]` is an array that contains nothing. So the type of its `length` property is the literal type `0`, not `number`; the type of your `2` literal is the literal type `2`; the error is there because the type `0` has no overlap with the type `2`.

Comment: Great explanation! I ran into this issue when checking the length of an array whose type was specified as [MyType] instead of MyType[]. Apparently, as you explained, the former implies a tuple containing a single MyType object, not an array at all. Go figure.

Comment: @MikeMiller - Yes, exactly, `[MyType]` is an array with exactly one `MyType` in it, neither more nor less. `MyType[]` (or `Array<MyType>`) is an array with zero or more `MyType` elements in it. Tuples are surprisingly useful, but not something JavaScript people expect unless they also have a background in some other language that has tuples (or of course, [math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple)).