# Bootstrap modal not closing on pressing backspace key

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have several bootstrap modals in my application. when there is a modal and I pressed backspace key the popup never closes instead the back portion of web page navigates last history page visited. How can I make the bootstrap modal close when backspace is pressed?

Comment: This answer might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112127/prevent-backspace-from-navigating-back-with-jquery-like-googles-homepage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootstrap [issue 2908](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2908) reports this behavior.

For angular.js one solution could be dismiss the window on $routeChangeSuccess, this way:

```js
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
});
```

It could also be implemented as an [directive](http://www.ufthelp.com/2014/10/how-to-dismiss-angular-modal-on-url.html) or it could be registered as a [global behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762323/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-close-angular-ui-bootstrap-modal-when-route-chan).

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2ukw.png)

I added the function in ui-bootstrap. This way it takes the backspace event and closes the modal

```
case 8:
                 B.value.keyboard && (a.preventDefault (), and. $ Apply (function {) {
                     Z.dismiss (b.key, "backspace key press")
                 }));
                 Break;
```