# dropdown backspace issue in chrome - jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

How do I prevent backspace when the dropdown is open in chrome? The solution by @J.Money works in IE but not in chrome when dropdown list is open. using Chrome Version 43.0.2357.134
Found solution for backspace at [Prevent BACKSPACE from navigating back with jQuery (Like Google's Homepage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112127/prevent-backspace-from-navigating-back-with-jquery-like-googles-homepage/31711184#31711184)
but still does not work when dropdown is open

Comment: Have you try `event.keyCode`? see [this](https://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.ui.keyCode/) link for more imforamtion.

Comment: yes I am using event.keycode for backspace its 8.             $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
            //console.log(e.srcElement.type);
            if (e.which === 8 && !$(e.target).is("input:not([readonly]):not([type=radio]):not([type=checkbox]), textarea, [contentEditable], [contentEditable=true]")) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });