# Debugging help needed: Prevent backspace from navigating back

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, backspace

I have a [webapp](http://www.scottseverance.us/html/time_calculator.htm) which uses the backspace key for its own purposes. I've long had the following function, called on `document.keyup`, which has worked without issue for years:

```
function keyupKeys (evt) {
  if(this.activeElement.id == 'q') return true; //ignore input to the search box
  if(!evt) var evt = window.event;
  var code = evt.keyCode;

  //handle special keys:
  switch(code) {
    case  9: // tab
    case 39: // right arrow
      press('colon'); break;
    case 37: // left arrow
      press('colon');
      press('colon'); break;
    case 13: // enter
      press('eq'); break;
    case  8: // backspace
      press('bs'); break;
    case 46: // delete
    case 144:// numpad clear
      press('c'); break;
    case 27: // esc
      press('ac'); break;
    default: // Not a key this function handles
      return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

Recently, I've discovered that Chrome in Windows and Chromium on Linux have started navigating back when backspace is pressed. This didn't used to be the case. I have yet to test other browsers.

Related questions on SO led me to modify the backspace case thus:

```
case  8: // backspace
  if(evt.preventDefault) evt.preventDefault();
  press('bs'); break;
```

However, this change had no effect. Furthermore, since the browser is navigating back, I can't use any of the debugging tools in the Javascript console, so I have no idea what's going on.

Can anyone explain what's happening and suggest a way to fix it?

Comment: What version of Chrome are you seeing the issue in? Your web app seems to work for me with backspace.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister: I'm currently using Chromium Version 43.0.2357.130 Ubuntu 14.04. I first discovered the problem earlier in the week on my work machine, which is Windows 7. I don't know the Chrome version, but it's set to auto-update.

Comment: the only hack I know for this is to pick something on the page and make sure it has `focus` when the page loads, a textbox works great. otherwise, don't take away my backspace

Comment: Interesting. My Chrome version is 44.0.2403.155 (64-bit), for reference.

Comment: Do not `var evt` - just use the `evt` you declared in the functions arguments!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent BACKSPACE from navigating back with jQuery (Like Google's Homepage)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112127/prevent-backspace-from-navigating-back-with-jquery-like-googles-homepage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11112169/713735) made me think that the problem could be caused by calling my function on keyup rather than keydown. I distinctly remember that when I first wrote this code a long time ago I used keyup to solve some sort of problem; what it was I no longer recall. At any rate, I created the following function to be called `onkeydown`. It seems to have solved the problem.

```
function keydownKeys(evt) {
  if(this.activeElement.id == 'q') return true; //ignore input to the search box
  if(!evt) var evt = window.event;
  var code = evt.keyCode;
  if(code == 8) {
    if(evt.preventDefault) {
      evt.preventDefault(); //kill backspace triggering back button
    }
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should listen on `keydown`, not `keyup` event.