# keyup on div for backspace not alerting keycode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
 $("div").live("keyup",function(event){
 var code=(event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which); 
 alert(code);return false;
 });

});</script>
</head>

<body>
<div tabindex="0">We will be performing network maintenance today starting at 18:00 UTC - expect a brief scheduled outage</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is alerting keycode for all buttons but on pressing backspace button the back button of browser comes in action.How can i prevent it?

Comment: `keydown` is working for me, check here http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/wgUD7/

Comment: Here is another question with many great answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495219/how-can-i-prevent-the-backspace-key-from-navigating-back

Comment: @Webtecher BTW, use `on` method instead of `live`. The last is deprecated.

Comment: @adeneo may you delete your first comment as it is very deviating to future visitors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `keydown` event instead:

```
$("div").live("keydown", function(event) {
    var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which); 
    alert(code);
    return false;
});
```

Meanwhile, key code for backspace is `8`.

**Try it:** http://jsfiddle.net/qfET2/