# How to detach event in IE 6 7 8 9 using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, bookmarklet

This is a partial code, not the full version.

I have a highlighter that highlights a specific html element when the **mouse hovers**.

I also have a **click event and listener**.

My problem is : the **highlighter event/listener** does not detach when using Internet Explorer v6 v7 v8 v9

What am I doing wrong?

This is how I attach the event and start the event listener:

```
if (document.body.addEventListener) {
                        //alert(11);
                        document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', handler, false);
                    } else if (document.body.attachEvent) {
                        //alert(12);
                        var ff=function(e) {
                            return handler(e || window.event);
                        };
                        //alert(ff);
                        document.body.attachEvent('onmousemove', ff);
                    } else {
                        //alert(13);
                        document.body.onmousemove = handler;
                    }
```

This is how I stop the `onmousemove`/`mouse` event/listener :

```
if (document.body.removeEventListener) {
                    document.body.removeEventListener('mousemove', handler, false);
                } else if (document.body.detachEvent) {
                    document.body.detachEvent('onmousemove', function(e) {
                        return handler(e || window.event);
                    });
                } else {
                    document.body.removeAttribute("onmousemove");
                }
```

This is how I stop the `onclick`/`click` event/listener:

```
if (document.body.removeEventListener) {
                    document.body.removeEventListener('click', ClosetAffairHighlighter.highlightClick, false);
                } else if (document.body.detachEvent) {
                    document.body.detachEvent('onclick', ClosetAffairHighlighter.highlightClick);
                } else {
                    document.body.removeAttribute("onclick");
                }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

base on [this article](http://zh.scribd.com/doc/92683134/210/Internet-Explorer-Event-Handlers), a cross-browser event handler can be :

```
var EventUtil = {
    addHandler: function(element, type, handler) {
        if (element.addEventListener) {
            element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
        } else if (element.attachEvent) {
            element.attachEvent("on" + type, handler);
        } else {
            element["on" + type] = handler;
        }
    },
    removeHandler: function(element, type, handler) {
        if (element.removeEventListener) {
            element.removeEventListener(type, handler, false);
        } else if (element.detachEvent) {
            element.detachEvent("on" + type, handler);
        } else {
            element["on" + type] = null;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Rats, this NCZ link is no longer active, is there an alternative article or link that could be referred to?

Comment: @Danjah Thanks for reminding, this gist: https://gist.github.com/objectfoo/4144898 is a repository for the code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass to `detachEvent` the function you added with `attachEvent`. In your code you're passing a new one (they have the same `toString()` and would do the same thing but they're not the same).

You should make `ff` global with

```
var ff;
if (document.body.addEventListener) {
    document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', handler, false);
} else if (document.body.attachEvent) {
     ff=function(e) {
          return handler(e || window.event);
     };
```

and then call

```
else if (document.body.detachEvent) {
     document.body.detachEvent('onmousemove', ff);
}
```

to remove the listener in old IE.

**Note :** I'm really doubtful about the `document.body.removeAttribute("onclick");` : is there really a case in which this would be useful ?

Comment: i will have this tryed ... 10x