# Preventing backspace to go back from the current form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the below JavaScript function to prevent backspace from going back.

```
function preventBackspace(e) {
    var evt = e || window.event;
    if (evt) {
        var keyCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
        if (keyCode === 8) {
            if (evt.preventDefault) {
                evt.preventDefault();
            } else {
                evt.returnValue = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have added `onkeydown="preventBackspace();"` to all the text boxes.

I have two radio buttons and two textboxes which when checked make the other textbox readonly. When hitting the backspace key it is not going to back page, but I am not able to delete from the editable text box. Please suggest. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent the backspace key from navigating back?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495219/how-can-i-prevent-the-backspace-key-from-navigating-back)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user is currently focused on a textbox, the backspace key does *not* cause the browser to go back.  The backspace in a textbox is used to delete a character - and since you've added `preventDefault()`, you're stopping that behavior from happening.

If your goal is to prevent the user from accidentally leaving the form before they are finished, you can use `window.onbeforeunload` to display a warning message that allows the user to cancel navigation:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Are you sure you want to leave this page?  Your current entries" +
        " will be lost.";
};
```

Comment: It should work in Chrome.  I use this method, and Chrome is my main browser.  I don't know about Safari.

Comment: It's my mistake..unload has some cross browser issues.. attaching onbeforeunload will work in Chrome.. Sorry for this

Comment: It is working now, but when im saving the form it still shows up?

Comment: When the user is submitting the form, then you will need to disable the message.  For example, `<input type="submit" onclick="window.onbeforeunload=null;" .. />`.

Comment: No its still firing it when clicking submit button, also the message is repetitive. It says Are you sure you want to navigate away from the page? Are you sure you want to leave this page?  Your current entries will be lost

Comment: Ya browsers add their own message on top, so you'll need to edit it to make sense.