# Unable to backspace in input type="number" using Chrome 64bit in Ubuntu 14.04. Works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, types, numbers, backspace

I am trying to use the code below posted by Biff MaGriff for an [earlier solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495219/how-can-i-prevent-the-backspace-key-from-navigating-back) to preventing backspace use that causes the browser to go back a page in history. My issue is that the code will not allow backspace (deletion) of characters in type="number".

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    var preventKeyPress;
    if (e.keyCode == 8) {
        var d = e.srcElement || e.target;
        switch (d.tagName.toUpperCase()) {
            case 'TEXTAREA':
                preventKeyPress = d.readOnly || d.disabled;
                break;
            case 'INPUT':
                preventKeyPress = d.readOnly || d.disabled ||
                    (d.attributes["type"] && $.inArray(d.attributes["type"].value.toLowerCase(), ["radio", "checkbox", "submit", "button"]) >= 0);
                break;
            case 'DIV':
                preventKeyPress = d.readOnly || d.disabled || !(d.attributes["contentEditable"] && d.attributes["contentEditable"].value == "true");
                break;
            default:
                preventKeyPress = true;
                break;
        }
    }
    else
        preventKeyPress = false;

    if (preventKeyPress)
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

My code is as follows:

```
<input id="tesnprice" type="number" step=0.01 name="price" size="50" maxlength="6" />
```

Comment: It does allow backspace in inputs of type number. http://jsfiddle.net/adamconway/htm09sgo/  What is the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the response Adam. Further testing, you are correct that it works in another browser. I hadn't checked that. On Ubuntu 14.04 with Chrome 64bit browser, it does not. In Firefox it works fine. Will try to adjust the title to convey this update.

Comment: Hmm.  Chrome (36) on Win 8 works fine.  have you tried my fiddle in your chrome or some other code of your own?

Comment: Have seen this on another system in Firefox. Seems to work intermittently depending upon OS and browser. I've decided just to change the type="text" and all works well. Tested it in jsfiddle and it still has issues... Not going to bother with it unless someone else wants to experiment.