# In Electron Framework, Can I access clipboard?

Tags: electron

I am new to Electron framework, I wanna know does it have access to native resources like 
- Clipboard
- Keypress (not on my web page, globally. Like a keyboard hook on windows)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is in the [clipboard](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/clipboard.md#clipboard) API.

There is also a [global shortcut API](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/global-shortcut.md#global-shortcut). Check out this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829839/disable-backspace-in-atom-shell/30831373#30831373) where I gave an example of how it works.

Here is an example of some basic read/write operations using the [clipboard](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/clipboard.md#clipboard) API:

```
const {clipboard} = require('electron');
clipboard.writeText('Example String');
let clipboardStr = clipboard.readText();
```

The 'Example String' is the text you would add to the clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

```
const {clipboard} = require('electron')
clipboard.writeText('Example String', 'selection')
console.log(clipboard.readText('selection'))
```

Comment: Note that this uses the Linux-specific 'selection' clipboard instead of the 'normal' one (that exists on all OSes). Remove 'selection' in the two calls (or replace it with 'clipboard') to use the default clipboard.